How can we get html element from form element change events?
We are creating CefSharp browser to automate testing for any website.
for that, user can interact with the website and we can capture all form fill-up and store it.
Please help me to find solution to get the element(button, textbox, dropdown, checkbox, radio i.e form elements) values once user interacted with it.
I've tried IKeyboardHandler, but in this we're getting the position where the things happened for key press events (specially for textbox).
Inherited with IKeyboardHandler interface.
I have two methods to implement as below:
public bool OnPreKeyEvent(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, KeyType type, int windowsKeyCode, int nativeKeyCode, CefEventFlags modifiers, bool isSystemKey, ref bool isKeyboardShortcut)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public bool OnKeyEvent(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, KeyType type, int windowsKeyCode, int nativeKeyCode, CefEventFlags modifiers, bool isSystemKey)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

Now I want to get html element(textbox here) that interacted in this OnKeyEvent event. Is it possible to get it?

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].
